# Custom nifi processor OnEnable anotation is not being called

Tags: java, apache, apache-nifi

I have a processor that starts a connection to an elastic search, I'm doing this connection on a method that has the anotation @OnEnabled, but this method is not being called:

```
@OnEnabled
public void onEnabled(final ConfigurationContext configurationContext) {
 <code connection goes here>
}
```

I have tried the connection on the onTrigger method and it works, but this kills the machine.

My processor extends from the AbstractProcessor method.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want @OnScheduled which is called when you start the processor, then you would close connections in @OnStopped.

Another option is to lazily create the connection in onTrigger by checking if the connection is null, and if it is then initialize it.

See the description of @OnEnabled here:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#component-lifecycle

> "Note that this annotation will be ignored if applied to a
>   ReportingTask or Processor. For a Controller Service, enabling and
>   disabling are considered lifecycle events, as the action makes them
>   usable or unusable by other components."